# Get featured image on Blog Index

Tags: post-thumbnails

I've been trying to use the "featured image" from the home (the blog index) with no luck. It's working for every single page, but it's not working for the home.

The code looks something like this:

```
// Don't use on single posts
    if (!is_single()) {
        if (is_home()) {
            if (function_exists('wp_get_attachment_thumb_url')) {
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full');
                $featured_image = $img[0];
            }
        } else {
            if (function_exists('wp_get_attachment_thumb_url') && has_post_thumbnail()) {
                $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full');
                $featured_image = $img[0];
            }
        }
        if ($featured_image) { ?>
            // A lot of code...
        <?php }
    }
```

I already tried to obtain the thumbnail using the **_thumbnail_id** meta. Same result.

This code is placed on the functions file, I believe that the issue is that it's trying to get the loop/posts featured image.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you are referring to the 'page for posts', then try (only relevant section of your code shown):

```
if (is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_option('page_for_posts')),'full'); 
    $featured_image = $img[0];
} else {
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest anyone doing this consider the following adjustments:

1. Get the ID of the current page/post/index using `get_queried_object()`. For a blog index that's set to a page this will return the correct page ID.
2. If all you want is the full-sized image use `wp_get_attachment_url()` instead of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`

Here's a quick function I'd use to achieve this in a simpler way:

```
/**
 * Custom Featured Image
 */
function custom_featured_image() {
    $queried_obj = get_queried_object();

    // Don't use on single posts (JUST FOR THIS DEMO)
    if ( is_single() ) return;

    // Get the featured image ID
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $queried_obj->ID );

    // Get the URL for the full sized image
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id );

    return $image_src;
}
```

I personally like to avoid excessive nested conditional logic, using a function can help with this.

Answer (score 1):

This works..

```
<section id="banner" style="background-image: <?php if (is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
    $blog_home_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
    echo 'url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($blog_home_id, 'full').')'; 
} else { 
echo 'url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'full').')';
}
?>;">
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 quick options, via the template file using `the_post_thumbnail` for the loop. I assume your outputting the data in a typical blog format and thus your function above won't work or act very weird inside the loop.

Instead try something like this in the actual template file where your main loop is (maybe index.php or loop.php) :

```
  //loop starts
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
   the_post_thumbnail();
   }
   //the_content(); and other stuff
   //loop ends
```

Or if you want to use an action instead to alter the main loop you can use `pre_get_posts`, for example in your functions.php file.

Something like:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_featured_image' );

function add_featured_image( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        //your image code
    }

}
```

Notice that the above is checking 2 parameters, the main query and the home page, it is very important to check if it is the main query, otherwise it will alter all queries.

Reference:http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: You haven't read the question properly, the user doesn't want to get the blog posts inside theloop, he wants the featured image of the page that's assigned to the Blog index page, which is what I want to do too. `has_post_thumbnail()` seems to work fine on page.php, but returns `false` when used in index.php

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the "posts page" $post will start with the first "post" in the loop.
One way could be by using the "queried object".

Print $wp_query and you will see:
[queried_object]
[posts]
[post]
-- note: queried_object will/might be empty in some pages

```
// get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_queried_object(), 'fullsize' );

// or

function ABC_get_the_thumbnail_url() {

    $queried_object = get_queried_object();

    $thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $queried_object, 'fullsize' );

    if ( ! $thumbnail_url ) {

        return get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-path/default-image.jpg';

        // or from a default option

    }

    return $thumbnail_url;

}
```